# SQL - Using a third query to compare results of two previous

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two querys in my database that return totals from different tables, i am then running a third query to compare these totals?

I need to perform this in a single statment so i can publish on my asp.net site. can these queries be combined?

Below are the three querys

**qry_control_d_total**

```
SELECT 
  tbl_control_d.processed_date, 
  Sum(tbl_control_d.dc_amt) 
AS 
  SumOfdc_amt, 
  tbl_currency.cur_type
FROM 
  tbl_control_d 
INNER JOIN 
  tbl_currency 
ON 
  tbl_control_d.cur_code = tbl_currency.cur_code
GROUP BY 
  tbl_control_d.processed_date, tbl_currency.cur_type
AS 
  qry_control_d_total;
```

**qry_sap_total**

```
SELECT 
   tbl_sap.doc_date, 
Sum
   (tbl_sap.dc_amt) 
AS 
   SumOfdc_amt, 
   tbl_sap.cur_type
FROM 
   tbl_sap
GROUP BY 
   tbl_sap.doc_date, 
   tbl_sap.cur_type
AS 
   qry_sap_total;
```

**final query**

```
SELECT 
   qry_control_d_total.processed_date, 
   qry_control_d_total.cur_type, 
   [qry_control_d_total].[sumofdc_amt]-[qry_control_d_total].[sumofdc_amt] 
AS 
   balance, 
   qry_control_d_total.SumOfdc_amt, 
   qry_sap_total.SumOfdc_amt
FROM 
   qry_control_d_total 
INNER JOIN 
   qry_sap_total 
ON 
   (qry_control_d_total.processed_date = qry_sap_total.doc_date) 
AND 
   (qry_control_d_total.cur_type = qry_sap_total.cur_type);
```

any suggestions welcome

---

this is the sub i am using within my vb.net page

```
sub page_load
    lblyear.text = dateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")
    Dim objconn as new oledbconnection("provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=F:\CCMI\asp\db\control.mdb")
    Dim objcmd As Oledbcommand
    Dim objRdr as OledbDatareader
    Dim strCmd as string
    Dim objDA as oleDbDataAdapter
    if not ispostback then
        '****************
        objcmd = new oledbcommand("SELECT...", objconn)
                objconn.open()
                objRdr = objcmd.executereader()
                dgbal_mc_roi.datasource = objrdr
                dgbal_mc_roi.databind()
                objrdr.close()
                objconn.close()
    end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to use your previous querys as derived tables:

```
SELECT 
   qry_control_d_total.processed_date, 
   qry_control_d_total.cur_type, 
   qry_control_d_total.[sumofdc_amt]-qry_control_d_total.[sumofdc_amt] 
AS 
   balance, 
   qry_control_d_total.SumOfdc_amt, 
   qry_sap_total.SumOfdc_amt
FROM (  SELECT tbl_control_d.processed_date, Sum(tbl_control_d.dc_amt) AS SumOfdc_amt, tbl_currency.cur_type
        FROM tbl_control_d 
        INNER JOIN tbl_currency 
        ON tbl_control_d.cur_code = tbl_currency.cur_code
        GROUP BY tbl_control_d.processed_date, tbl_currency.cur_type) AS qry_control_d_total 
INNER JOIN (SELECT tbl_sap.doc_date, Sum(tbl_sap.dc_amt) AS SumOfdc_amt, tbl_sap.cur_type
            FROM tbl_sap
            GROUP BY tbl_sap.doc_date, tbl_sap.cur_type) AS qry_sap_total 
ON qry_control_d_total.processed_date = qry_sap_total.doc_date
AND qry_control_d_total.cur_type = qry_sap_total.cur_type
```

Comment: this works when i test it in my database, but when i try on my .net site i get "qry_control_d_total.processed_date" was not found on selected datasource??? Really appreciate the help though as this is much further than i have been getting!

Comment: @Barry - Maybe it needed to explicitly name the derived tables with an `AS`, I added on my answer. Anyway, it can be many number of things, you need to give us more information what database engine are you using?, how do you connect to your database from your site?

Comment: sub page_load lblyear.text = dateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") Dim objconn as new oledbconnection("provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=F:\CCMI\asp\db\control.mdb") Dim objcmd As Oledbcommand Dim objRdr as OledbDatareader Dim strCmd as string Dim objDA as oleDbDataAdapter if not ispostback then '**************** objcmd = new oledbcommand("SELECT...", objconn) objconn.open() objRdr = objcmd.executereader() dgbal_mc_roi.datasource = objrdr dgbal_mc_roi.databind() objrdr.close() objconn.close() end if end sub

Comment: @Barry - So this is Access and basic, right?. Did you try with the new query I posted?, other than that, I wouldn't know how to fix this error.

Comment: i have got it working, query was absolutely fine, my issue was with my datagrid picking the correct fields to display from the query.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing one thing

If you are performing these queries in a stored procedure,

take the results of the first query into a temporary table and
the results of the second table into another temporary table

write a join query for those two temporary tables!

Comment: Stored procedure in Access along with temporary tables?

Comment: I am so sorry sir
I thought you are doing it in sql server.